# Should I create swap partition if I have many RAM?

Tags: linux, opensuse

I have 8/16/32 GB of RAM memory. In what case I should create a swap partition? Always or didn't need a swap partition?

**UPD**
I am Windows user, since 3.11. I don't know about linux nothing, sorry.
I'm using SSD disks and reading now this article https://lizards.opensuse.org/2015/02/06/ssd-configuration-for-opensuse/ where black on white written "Don’t create a swap partition. If you already have enough memory..."

Should I trust this man?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run Software that may use much RAM it might be better to add a swap, otherwise the System might become very unstable or crash if all free RAM is used up. So it is never wrong to add a few GB to the SWAP Partition, especially on Servers.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Max Kehm. I updated my questions, because get minus 1 and not underastand "Why?".

Comment: @user4611478 you probably get -1 because your question would feel itself much better on something like superuser. SO is for programming-related questions, not computer-related.

Comment: "not computer-related"?? Hmm...  I updated my question.. I don't see about programming in my question.

Comment: If you choose to use SWAP on SSD you could reduce the swapiness to ensure that your system only uses the SWAP when no free RAM is availible. This could reduce the load on the SWAP to a minimum.